# What should I do to have one intent as a parent and a follow-up of another intent at the same time?

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am working on a chatbot project built with Dialogflow. Mainly, it is about answering FAQs and making other things like phone calls or scheduling via Google Calendar. I need to have some follow-up intents accessible form the root level, but I don't want to create duplicates of them with the same functionality. Also, I feel like adding a lot of intents will be faster with modifying JSON rather than using Dialogflow GUI. So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to have one intent as a follow-up of another intent and as a parent intent by itself simultaneously?
2. For adding new intents is it enough just to follow structure of other intents that are similar to this one in terms of functionality and just change training phrases, answers, and id in the new JSON file?

I've tried adding a new object associated with a new intent to "agent.json" file, but the agent remained the same once I uploaded a changed version. I thought of just taking id of one follow-up intent and add it to the list with starting intents, so I have this intent accessible from different places. However, it doesn't work.

As you can see in the code snippet, there are some starting intents for Google Assistant. However, there is no such thing for a general Dialogflow window, so it is unclear for me, how is it possible to add new intents modifying JSON files of the agent.

```
"googleAssistant": {
...
"startIntents": [
      {
        "intentId": *id of my new intent here*,
        "signInRequired": false
      },
...
]
...
}

The agent remains the same despite changes in JSON files.
```

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to have an Intent as both a Followup Intent and as a top-level Intent - but probably not in the way you're thinking about either.

First - keep in mind that an Intent represents *what the user has said*, and not what you are doing with what they have said.

So the simple approach is to not have it as a Followup Intent at all - you don't need it there. In fact, there are probably very few cases where you actually want a Followup Intent. Instead, have it as a regular Intent, but keep track of other information to determine where in the conversation you are and what information you have and act based on this.

See [Thinking for Voice, Design Conversations Not Logic](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/thinking-for-voice-design-conversations-not-logic-7c60869451f1) for more on this approach.